# REST Service Getting 400 bad request

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, rest

I have created a restful web service in c#. I am getting 400 bad request error when I call the POST method. I am checking my requests in fiddler and the POST requests are perfectly fine. I don't understand what is wrong with my program.

Here are some of the code snippets. If any of you need any other code to have a look at please ask.

Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRead
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetCard", Method = "POST")]
    someObject GetCard(Session session);
}
```

The NFCSession is an object which has a int variable of name session.

Client generating POST request

```
public void GetCard()
{
        string strGetCard = "http://localhost:8384/Reader/GetCard";

        byte[] dataByte = GenerateNFCSession(63315152);

        HttpWebRequest POSTRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strGetCard);
        POSTRequest.Method = "POST";
        POSTRequest.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=UTF-8";
        POSTRequest.ContentLength = dataByte.Length;

        Stream POSTstream = POSTRequest.GetRequestStream();

        POSTstream.Write(dataByte, 0, dataByte.Length);

        HttpWebResponse POSTResponse = (HttpWebResponse)POSTRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader =
          new StreamReader(POSTResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        Console.WriteLine("Response");
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd().ToString());
}
```

XML Generator

```
private static byte[] GenerateXML(int sessionID)
    {
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Session");
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("session");
                xmlWriter.WriteString(sessionID.ToString());
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlWriter.Flush();
        xmlWriter.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(mStream.ToArray().ToString());
        return mStream.ToArray();

    }
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
System.Web,Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true"
automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

POST Request XML from Fiddler

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Session>
  <session>63315152</session>
</Session>
```

I get this error

```
The server encountered an error processing the request.
```

NOTE: When I provide XmlSerializer Format Attribute it works fine. But I want my service to work for JSON requests as well at a later point. And from my point of view Its not necessary to explicitly provide the format attribute. I seriously don't understand what is wrong with this code.

Guys Please HELP!!!

Comment: if REST Api, leave WCF, use ASP.NET web Api, it's simpler

Comment: Do you mean ASP.NET MVC 4?

Comment: The link: http://www.asp.net/web-api, Web Api is not ASP.NET MVC 4, both are just in the same package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Web Service is working fine now.

The changes I made are in the DataContract Attribute.

Initially it was like this:

```
[DataContract]
```

I changed it to this:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
```

And it started working...

TIP: When you run your web service you can see sample POST requests in '/help' page of the webservice. I never paid any attention to this page. But it is very useful. When I compared this example with the actual request in Fiddler I found out that the namespaces are different. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<enableWebScript />` inside behavior tag:

```
...
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
...
```

It's discussed here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/fb48999f-cd41-49b8-ae9a-f0c8f5aebbd2

Comment: I am not getting this option in my xml at all.. However, i think if you use webHttp endpoint you don't need this modification.